# swift 3 slider thumb image position misplaced

Tags: ios, swift3, uislider

I updated slider thumb image using following code and still its displaying with some gap.  `slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Seekbar"), for: .normal)` [image]

Here is my complete code

```
self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "PauseBig"), for: .normal)
let duration : CMTime = mediaPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
slider.value = 0
slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Seekbar"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: what your minimum track of slider

Comment: I have updated please check my question

Comment: add   slider.value = 0

Comment: i already set value 0 in storyboard

Comment: but add progrmatically once and check once

Comment: i have updated my code and no change same problem

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: I cant attach because of its size and security reasons , But i have written the same code which i was mentioned in question.

Comment: ok then try once in sample project ,if you not get the answer attch here

Comment: @MaheshNarla what about the image size ??

Comment: i have used 15@1x, 30@2x and 45@3x

Comment: Are you sure there is no transparent area in you png file?